# Ada: flexible Text_IO File_Type for redirecting output with SET_OUTPUT?

Tags: ada

I've inherited a project that has two output modes, console and plain-text file.  The project uses Ada.Text_IO.SET_OUTPUT to select one or the other.

I want to create a third SET_OUTPUT option, one that can easily re-direct output to a variety of formats other than stdout or a disk file.  I'd like the output to be some sort of in-RAM object or "file" so that it can be quickly read by multiple clients.  I also need to keep the code portable, so ideally the solution would stick to the standard libraries.

I've tried instantiations of Sequential_IO, but the code base is too large and inconsistent (wrt overloadings and renamings of Text_IO's procedures and whether Text_IO is called by full dot notation) to quickly and reliably replace calls.

I must be uncreative (and I'm certainly new to Ada), but the solution I keep coming to seems overly complex and convoluted--creating a container of Text_IO's File_Type in a memory pool managed at a low level; then SET_OUTPUT to that in-RAM file, from where it can be pushed or pulled to clients.

I hope I'm missing something, and that someone can help me find an simpler way.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to use text_io for both because the same line of code can write to either a file or the console based on some runtime state or because it is just convenient to use text IO for both and different lines of code write to the console vs others lines of code that write to a file?

Comment: The former -- there's a global runtime variable of Text_IO.FileType (so either a file system file name or stdout).  I'd like to add something like a "third" option of directing the text to an in-memory object so that it can be accessed more flexibly by a variety of clients and without causing DASD I/O.  I'd also like to avoid manually finding-replacing Put, Get, Put_Line, etc. calls because he code base is large and inconsistent.  It is looking from the other answers like that simply isn't possible, so I will need to pipe to some external program or re-write the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Text_IO` is specifically for files, so there's no portable way to use it to write to memory. The normal way to allow writing to files, memory, or anything else you can define, is to use streams, but that would require replacing most uses of `Text_IO` to use streams instead. If that's acceptable, then `Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams` allows writing to Current_Output as a stream.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re not going to change all the `Text_IO` calls, you’re going to be stuck with textual output to your chosen in-memory (for example) storage, which will probably mean textual content (unless your historical developers have adhered rigorously to parsable format standards!)

Assuming GNAT, the way IO deals with files is described in the [GNAT Reference Manual](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/the_implementation_of_standard_i_o.html); particularly, there’s no requirement for a file to be a regular disk file, so long as it’s accessible via C system calls, e.g. `fopen()`. So you could pipe to a log storage manager.

On the other hand you could just use a shared file (see the [FORM strings](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/the_implementation_of_standard_i_o.html#form-strings) section of the GNAT RM).

Does the system have just one possible text file output? That would make things easier ...

Comment: Thank you.  I'm actually fine with maintaining line-oriented text output, I was just hoping to avoid either piping to an external program or causing DASD I/O.  It looks from your answers and the others like that's not possible without re-writing the Put, Get, Put_Line, etc. calls to use something other than Text_IO.  It's disappointing, but it looks like there will be hours of find-review-replace in my future!

Answer (score 1):

I'd give a try with something like this:

```
  type Extended_File_Type is record
    Is_Normal : Boolean;
    File      : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
    Special   : Integer;  --  <- Dummy, replace by your fancy in-RAM object.
  end record;

  procedure Put_Line (EFile : Extended_File_Type; S : String) is
  begin
    if EFile.Is_Normal then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Efile.File, S);
    else
      null;  --  Output to your special object.
    end if;
  end;
```